# How to access variables from an extended class in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, inheritance, scope

In most languages you can do something like the following:

```
class a {
    this.property = 'prop'
}

class b extends a {
    puts this.property //prints 'prop'
}
```

How does this work in ruby? My initial thought was something like

```
class A
    @property = 'prop'
end

class B < A
    puts @property
end
```

But this doesn't work. Ruby has the `self` keyword but that seems from what I can tell to be reserved for methods. Can classes inherit variables in ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes they can, and here's a snippet that shows how.

```
class A2
  def initialize
    @foo = 42
  end
end

class B2 < A2
  def print_foo
    puts @foo
  end
end

# Prints 42
B2.new.print_foo
```

The above code defines a class `A2`, with a constructor that defines and sets an instance variable `@foo`. Class `B2` extends `A2`, and defines a method that uses `@foo`.

I think the issue with your code is that `@property` is not assigned a value, as the assignment isn't in a method that gets called at any point.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You need to init instance variables in the `initialize` method.

See an example:

```
class A
  attr_accessor :property  

  def initialize
    self.property = 'prop'
  end
end

class B < A
end

puts B.new.property # prints "prop"
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables starting with an `@` sigil are *instance variables*. They belong to a particular instance (i.e. "object").

You have two objects in your code, one object is the class `A`, the second object is the class `B`. Each of those two objects has its own instance variables.

`A` has an instance variable called `@property` with the value `'prop'`. `B` has no instance variables, however, uninitialized instance variables evaluate to `nil` instead of raising an exception, so, you don't get an error, but it evaluates to `nil`.

You cant' inherit variables. The only thing you can inherit in Ruby, are methods:

```
class A
  def self.property
    'prop'
  end
end

class B < A
  puts property
end
# prop
```

Ruby also has class variables that start with an `@@` sigil. These are shared across the entire class hierarchy:

```
class A
  @@property= 'prop'
end

class B < A
  puts @@property
end
# prop
```

However, class variables are almost never used in Ruby, because of the wide scope they have, almost like globals.